# Proving that a solution exists

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

> Proof that there exists a $x>0$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\sin(x) = \frac{x}{2}$

I tried to use the intermediate value theorem, but I don't know how to apply it correctly. Obviously $\sin(\pi /2) = 1$ and $\sin(\pi)=0$, but I don't see how this should help me.

Comment: by the way $\sin \pi / 2 = 1$ and $\sin \pi = 0$ :-)

Comment: haha, I should know that by now. I shall edit my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \sin x - \frac x2$.

$f(\pi/2) = 1 - \frac \pi4 > 0$ while $f(\pi) = 0 - \pi/2 < 0$

Now use the intermediate value theorem to show that there exists a zero of $f(x)$ in $(\pi/2, \pi)$, which will also be the solution you were looking for :-)

---

Another way would be to compare their derivatives;  both $\sin x$ and $\frac x2$ are $0$ on the origin, and their derivatives are $\cos x $ and $\frac 12$ respectively.

Since for small $x$ you have $\cos x \sim 1$, you get that in a neighborhood of $0$ $\sin x$ is growing more than $\frac x2$, so immediately after $0$ you'll find the graph of $\sin x$ above the graph of $\frac x2$.

On the other hand $\sin x$ is periodic (or you can use the fact that is bounded) and is going to "come down" eventually, while $\frac x2$ won't; so after a while $x/2$ has to be above $\sin x$.

Since they are both continuos, their graph need to intersect in a point

(This also uses the intermediate value theorem, but it's a more "geometric" interpretation)

Comment: Wow thanks, that's a nice answer but I don't know if I may assume that $\pi/4 < 1$ is there any proper way to proof this?

Comment: @RubenMeijs Well since $\pi \sim 3.14159$, you get $\pi/4 < 1$. If instead you know "nothing" about $\pi$ you can use the second method I outlined. Or prove that $\pi < 4$, but then you have to define $\pi$ somehow :)

Comment: I think that for my analysis course I would have to use the first method, so then I think I may assume that we know that $3\leq \pi \leq 4$ which make your proof also work

Comment: @RubenMeijs Glad to be of help! ;-)

Comment: @RubenMeijs $\pi$ is a set number which is equals to 3.1415926539....(and so on).Maybe you can put in this equality but u will know that as long as $\pi<4$,you know that $\pi/4<1$